# (0/1 test methods passed) Help

Tags: apex, unit-test, method

I'm trying to make this test method work.

```
    //test
@isTest 
private class CoreValuesExtTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateCoreValues() {
       Core_Values__c cv = new Core_Values__c(Account__c='6', HSE__c='6', Professionalism_Integrity__c='6', Quality_Accuracy__c='6', Technology_Innovation__c='6', Value_for_Money__c='6', Timeliness__c='6');
       System.debug(cv.Account__c + cv.HSE__c + cv.Professionalism_Integrity__c + cv.Quality_Accuracy__c + cv.Technology_Innovation__c + cv.Value_for_Money__c + cv.Timeliness__c);

       // Insert book
       insert cv;

       // Retrieve the new book
       cv = [SELECT Account__c, HSE__c,Professionalism_Integrity__c,Quality_Accuracy__c,Technology_Innovation__c,Value_for_Money__c,Timeliness__c FROM Core_Values__c WHERE Id =:cv.Id];
       System.debug(cv.Account__c + cv.HSE__c + cv.Professionalism_Integrity__c + cv.Quality_Accuracy__c + cv.Technology_Innovation__c + cv.Value_for_Money__c + cv.Timeliness__c);

       // Test that the trigger correctly updated the price
       System.assertEquals('6', cv.Account__c);
       System.assertEquals('6', cv.HSE__c);
       System.assertEquals('6', cv.Professionalism_Integrity__c);
       System.assertEquals('6', cv.Quality_Accuracy__c);
       System.assertEquals('6', cv.Technology_Innovation__c);
       System.assertEquals('6', cv.Value_for_Money__c);
       System.assertEquals('6', cv.Timeliness__c);
    }
}
```

for this class

```
public class CoreValuesExt
{
    ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public boolean readonly {get; set;}
    public Core_Values__c cv {get; set;}
    public integer countEdit = 1;
    public string buttonValue {get; set;}
    public integer recordScan;

    public CoreValuesExt(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
    {
        this.sc = sc;
        cv = new Core_Values__c();
        cv.Account__c = sc.getid();

        readonly = true;
        buttonValue = 'Edit';
        recordScan = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Core_Values__c WHERE Account__c = :cv.Account__c];
       if (recordScan != 0){
       cv = [SELECT id, HSE__c, Professionalism_Integrity__c, Quality_Accuracy__c, Technology_Innovation__c, Timeliness__c, Value_for_money__c FROM Core_Values__c WHERE Account__c = :cv.Account__c];
        }

    }

    public ApexPages.PageReference Save()
    {
        return sc.Save();
    }

    public void ApplyAction()
    {
        countEdit++;
        Integer modolus = Math.mod(countEdit, 2);
        String total = cv.HSE__c + cv.Professionalism_Integrity__c + cv.Quality_Accuracy__c + cv.Technology_Innovation__c + cv.Value_for_Money__c + cv.Timeliness__c;
        if(modolus == 0)
        {
            readonly = false;
            buttonValue = 'Save';
        }
        else
        {
            if(total != 'nullnullnullnullnullnull')
               {
            if (recordScan == 0){
            insert cv;
            readonly = true;
            buttonValue = 'Edit';
            }
            else
            {
            update cv;
            readonly = true;
            buttonValue = 'Edit';
            }
            }
        }  

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the tests pass nothing, how do I make this work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: And where in your test do you instantiate your controller or call any method from it? If a user entered a record does the VF page come up? Think about the process, you need to replicate that as it does not just magically happen during a test.

Comment: @Eric I think this is the instantiation. Core_Values__c cv = new Core_Values__c(Account__c='6', HSE__c='6', Professionalism_Integrity__c='6', Quality_Accuracy__c='6', Technology_Innovation__c='6', Value_for_Money__c='6', Timeliness__c='6');

Comment: Okay, I already instantiated the CoreValuesExt class

Comment: @Eric How do I make sure the tests work?

Comment: @JustinCosio I dont see it instantiated anywhere.  http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm

Answer (score 0):

This may sound kind of basic, but the reason the test did not pass is because one of your assertions failed.  You need to find out which assertion failed so that you can debug the matter further.

Different tools provide different ways of doing this, but the Developer Console is a good one.  After you run the unit tests, it will show a red x next to the class that failed.  Double-clicking on that class and it will show the error, including line number.

Hope that is helpful.